# H2 database and Spring Data ignoring @Lob field annotation

Tags: java, spring-data, h2

I'm working with mysql database and Spring Data, where I have a column defined like this:

```
    @Lob
    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String messageContent;
```

This column is used to store large strings. It's working perfectly fine with mysql, but for unit tests I'm using H2 database instead. Looks like H2 is ignoring @Lob annotation and I get:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: string data, right truncation;  table: MESSAGE column: MESSAGE_CONTENT
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy189.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 147 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: string data, right truncation;  table: MESSAGE column: MESSAGE_CONTENT
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.enforceTypeLimits(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.generateAndCheckData(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertRowSet(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 156 common frames omitted
```

I cannot change column definition, H2 is used only for test cases. I'm thinking about changing column type manually, by executing ALTER TABLE statement, but maybe there is better workaround ?

Comment: I think that you are inserting in your tests something that is longer than the column definition. Try to remove the length and repeat tests to see if the default value (which should be the maximum legth) works.

Comment: How is your H2 schema being generated and applied?

Comment: Thank you for comments, schema is created automatically:  hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: Also, can you show us your test class? It would be good for helping you.

Comment: Looks like it was a problem with @Column(length = 1000), content was longer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for consistency across databases and also a Spring Data-like approach to content associated with Spring Data entities then why not give [Spring Content JPA](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) a look?  Like Spring Data it provides an abstraction and easy, opinionated programming model for your content needs.  You can add it with something like the following:-

> pom.xml

```
   <!-- Java API -->
   <dependency>          
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- REST API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-rest</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

> Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaStores
@Import("org.springframework.content.rest.config.RestConfiguration.class")
public class ContentConfig {

   @Value("/org/springframework/content/jpa/schema-drop-h2.sql")
   private Resource dropReopsitoryTables;

   @Value("/org/springframework/content/jpa/schema-h2.sql")
   private Resource dataReopsitorySchema;

   @Bean
   DataSourceInitializer datasourceInitializer() {
     ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator =
            new ResourceDatabasePopulator();

     databasePopulator.addScript(dropReopsitoryTables);
     databasePopulator.addScript(dataReopsitorySchema);
     databasePopulator.setIgnoreFailedDrops(true);

     DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
     initializer.setDataSource(dataSource());
     initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);

     return initializer;
   }
}
```

To associate content, add Spring Content annotations to your account entity.

> Example.java

```
@Entity
public class Example {

   // replace @Lob field with

   @ContentId
   private String contentId;

   @ContentLength
   private long contentLength = 0L;

   // if you have rest endpoints
   @MimeType
   private String mimeType = "text/plain";
```

Create a "store":

> ExampleStore.java

```
@StoreRestResource(path="examplesContent")
public interface ExampleStore extends ContentStore<Example, String> {
}
```

This is all you need to create REST endpoints @ `/examplesContent`.  When your application starts, Spring Content will look at your dependencies (seeing Spring Content JPA/REST), look at your `ExampleStore` interface and inject an implementation of that interface for JPA.  It will also inject a `@Controller` that forwards http requests to that implementation.  This saves you having to implement any of this yourself.

So...

`curl -X POST /examplesContent/{exampleId}`

with a multipart/form-data request will store the content in the database and associate it with the example entity whose id is `exampleId`.

`curl /examplesContent/{exampleId}`

will fetch it again and so on...supports full CRUD.

There are a couple of getting started guides and videos [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  The  reference guide is [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/jpa-index.html).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I report the solution here from comments. You are trying to insert in that field a content that is longer than the length specified in `@Column` annotation. Either adjust the annotation or check your content.